# Restlet jse2 client resource interface not visible from class loader

Tags: maven, osgi, restlet

I Followed this tutorial for my Restlet server in the Google App Engine: http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/21-restlet/318-restlet/303-restlet.html It works fine with the GWT client.

Now i'm trying to build a jse2 desktop client with OSGi and Restlet.

The code for the Restlet client in the OSGi bundle stay's the same as the tutorail provided.

When i start the OSGi Felix framework i also start the org.restlet.jar bundle who's exporting the restlet framework packages and i start a bundle with this code given in the toturail:

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("localhost:8888/contacts/123");
// Get the Contact object
ContactResource resource = cr.wrap(ContactResource.class);
Contact contact = resource.retrieve();
```

The ContactResoure interface is in the same package as the bundle activator but i still get this strange message: *java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface nl.nhl.minor.crm.desktop.restlet.ContactResource is not visible from class loader*

Is this problem related to OSGi or to Restlet? And how can I solve this problem?

The manifest files for the OSGi bundles are created by the maven bundle plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way of loading a class is easy:

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("http://127.0.0.1:8888/contacts/123");
Class<ContactResource> clazs = (Class<ContactResource>) cr.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass("your.package.name.ClassName");
cr.wrap(clazs);
```

This solution give you a other problem, the class isn't imported by the org.restlet bundle.

See [import package without edit the manifest file in org.restlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433657/import-package-without-edit-the-manifest-file-in-org-restlet) for my question about that problem.

Comment: didn't find a solution but a different thread about this issue (hoping for some new insights there): https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/issues/6